# Find strings between two tags with regex in Qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt, parsing

can anybody help me with this?

I have a string which contains N substrings, delimited by tags and I have to get ALL of the substrings. The string is like

> STARTfoo barENDSTARThi there!ENDSTARTstackoverflowrulezEND

I would like to get all the strings between START/END tags, I tried with a couple of regular expressions with no luck:

> (START)(.*)(END)   gives me ALL the contend between the first and last tag
>
> (START)(\w+)(END)   gives me no result

The code is much simple:

```
QString l_str "STARTfoo barENDSTARThi there!ENDSTARTstackoverflowrulezEND"; 
QRegExp rx("(START)(\w+)(END)");
QStringList list;
int pos = 0;
while ((pos = rx.indexIn(l_str, pos)) != -1)
{
    list << rx.cap(1);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
qWarning() << list;
```

I'd like a resulting list like:

> STARTfoo barEND
>
> STARThi there!END
>
> STARTstackoverflowrulezEND

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `QRegex` accept non-greedy elements like: `START(.*?)END`?

Comment: @Galik: No, `QRegularExpression` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rx.setMinimal(true)` with `.*` to make it lazy:

```
QRegExp rx("START.*END");
rx.setMinimal(true);
```

See the [`QRegExp::setMinimal` docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#setMinimal):

> Enables or disables minimal matching. If *minimal* is `false`, matching is greedy (maximal) which is the default.

Comment: Just a note: since I suggest removing capture groups (all `()`), just access the match value with `rx.cap(0);`.