# Extract the string between two words using RegEx in QT

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm trying to extract string between two words using QRegExp. For example:

```
<info><timestamp>54</timestamp></info><info><timestamp>67</timestamp></info>
```

Results:

```
<timestamp>54</timestamp>
<timestamp>67</timestamp>
```

So I'm using the following RegEx:

```
<info>.+?</info>
```

This RegEx works fine when using online RegEx test such as https://regexr.com (Two matches find).

[image]

But it does not work in QT 5.12 when I used the following code:

```
QRegExp rx("<info>.+?</info>");
rx.setMinimal(true);
QString recXML_ = "<info><timestamp>54</timestamp></info><info><timestamp>67</timestamp></info>";

int pos = 0;
int siz = 0;
while ((pos = rx.indexIn(recXML_, pos)) != -1)
{
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
    siz += pos;
    qDebug()<<rx.capturedTexts()[0];
}
```

But the while condition is never satisfied.

**Point:** The setMinimal solution ([Find strings between two tags with regex in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297341/find-strings-between-two-tags-with-regex-in-qt)) does not work for my problem.

Is anyone aware of this problem and a possible solution?

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work in QT"? What's your output?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37297407/3832970

Comment: Thanks, I enabled setMinimal(true), but it did not worked.

Comment: Remove the `?` from your regex pattern and provide more detail about the results you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, I removed ? and get the correct results (Two matches: "<info><timestamp>54</timestamp></info>" and
"<info><timestamp>67</timestamp></info>")